# mondrian filters does not remember their options when moving to a dimension

Tags: filter, mdx, pentaho, dimension, mondrian

I have found a bug that I would like to solve.
I have a mondrian cube that has some dimensions on columns, others on rows, and also some filters.
In the filters I have a calculated exception like this:

```
member [Credit type].[Except] as '([Credit type].[All Credit types] - [Credit type].[A])'
```

and in the end of the MDX query I use

```
where {[Credit type].[Except]}
```

(that means i want all credit types, except type A)

This measure is put as as filter, so is hidden in the cube view.
If i go to the OLAP navigator (top left tool), I see the "Credit type" is on filters and beside its name it says "((All)=Except)" ... if I click it, it show is using the "Except" i build (the checkbox "Except" is clicked, and the checkbox "All" is not)

All this works OK, but when i move this filter and use it as a dimension (a column dimension), it moves fine, besides its name it says "((All)=Except)", but when I clicked it, both checkboxes are unchecked so the filter is gone...

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Regards!

---- edit ----
I'm using biserver-ce 3.7.0.stable.44411